# Sms autofill not working when install from google play - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, sha1, autofill

When the user installs my app from Google Play, SMS reading is not applied and the `SMSBroadcastReceiver` class does not called
But it works when the APK is installed
What is the problem ?